# Integration with outlook

Tags: java, apache-flex, outlook, outlook-addin

We are in the process of developing a CRM application and for that we need to integrate with Microsoft Outlook.

Would you please tell me:

What is the best way to integrate with outlook so that we can send, receive, search emails, calendar items and contacts. Please note that we use Flex front end and Java back end
Are there readily available tools (commercial or open source) that we can use?
Can we integrate directly with MS Exchange server through pop or imap. I believe pop is bit restrictive, where we can't search emails. We really don't want to retrieve emails and store it locally
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I would integrate to Outlook with a **C# add-in**.

We do similar and use the credential cache when authenticating with a webservice within our crm.